# jQuery datatables plugin not working in force.com site pages

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, jquery, datatable

I am using the jQuery datatables plugin in visualforce page to display list of contacts in a table. This is working fine for administrator. When open the same page using force.com site, page displaying only data but not pagination,sorting, search text. Which mean force.com site not supporting jQuery datatables plugin for me.

Can any one help on this, how can i fix this issue.

thanks,

Comment: did u chk the browser console ? is the jquery datatables script getting loaded ?

Comment: It would be good to see a little of the code you're using. Does script load? Did you set the static resource to global access? Is there a conflict? Errors in browser dev tools? Sites is a web UI running in a browser, so "not support" seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your jQuery DataTables Static Resource record in Setup and make sure that its **Cache Control** property is set to **Public**, otherwise the Static Resource will not be accessible by a public site user.

[image]